# Raycast Calculates Distance With An Object Wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my character teleport in the game. But if character is closer to ground more than half of his height, it will not teleport in the clicked position, instead it will teleport a slighty bit up. But when I try to calculate distance between clicked position and the game object at the bottom, raycast2d calculates it wrong and it teleports character way too up.

```
public GameObject player;
public Vector2 groundChecker;
public float castDistance;
public LayerMask groundLayer;

public Collider2D playerCollider;
Vector2 playerTop;
Vector2 playerBottom;
private float playerHeight;
private float distanceFromBlockBottom;

void Update()
{
    //If character is on ground and left mouse button is clicked, check how far the point you clicked from the player and teleport
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && IsGrounded())
    {
        //Calculating distance between mouse clicked point and player point
        Vector2 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        Vector2 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 distanceFromPlayer = clickedPosition - playerPosition;

        //Checking if mouse clicked point is a game object that can't be teleported
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);

        //Getting players center height
        playerCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        playerTop = playerCollider.bounds.max;
        playerBottom = playerCollider.bounds.min;
        playerHeight = playerTop.y - playerBottom.y;

        Debug.Log(playerHeight);
        Debug.Log(distanceFromBlockBottom);

        if (hit.collider == null)
        {
            if (distanceFromPlayer.magnitude < 3)
            {
                CalculateBlockDistance();
                if(distanceFromBlockBottom < playerHeight / 2)
                {
                    Vector2 newHeight;
                    newHeight.y = playerHeight/2 - distanceFromBlockBottom;
                    newHeight.x = 0;
                    player.transform.position = newHeight + clickedPosition;
                }
                else
                {
                    player.transform.position = clickedPosition;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


public void CalculateBlockDistance()
{
    //Getting players center height
    playerCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    playerTop = playerCollider.bounds.max;
    playerBottom = playerCollider.bounds.min;
    playerHeight = playerTop.y - playerBottom.y;

    Vector2 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D bottomRay = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, -Vector2.up, 0.3f, groundLayer);

    if (bottomRay.collider != null && bottomRay.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        distanceFromBlockBottom = clickedPosition.y - bottomRay.distance;
    }
}

public bool IsGrounded()
{
    if(Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, groundChecker, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my code and can someone help me about how to make this method work. Thing I want is basically this

x = Player's height
y = distance between clicked position and nearest object

1. Send rays to 4 side
2. If it collides an object with Ground tag, calculate distance(y)
3. If distance(y) < x/2 (half of the height)
4. player.transform.position = clicked position + (x/2 - y)